# Navigation Bar click event - Android Application

Tags: java, android, navigationbar

I'm trying to handle a onClick event on the Navigation Bar in an Android Application.

Exactlyer, when the user clicks on the return button the Application must go back to the Main Activity ( in my case **"Start"** ) and not to the previous Activity.

In my application I have more Activities, which are all callable from every Activity, so when, for example, I'm in **"Start"**, I click a Button and I come to **"Karte"**, then from **"Karte"** I want to go to **"Einstellungen"**, then from **"Einstellungen"** I want return to the Main Activity **"Start"**, but I can't because when I click on the return button on the Nav. Bar I come only back to the previous Activity (**"Karte"**).

If anyone knows how to handle this, please answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** After starting `Einstellungen` from `Karte`, just finish `Karte` activity to remove it from `stack`:

```
//Karte.java 

Intent intentEinstellungen = new Intent(karte.this, Einstellungen.class);
startActivity(intentEinstellungen);

// Finish Karte
finish();
```

**2.** When navigation `back/home` icon pressed from `Einstellungen`, just call  `super.onBackPressed()` from method `onOptionsItemSelected()` to finish the `Einstellungen` activity.

```
//Einstellungen.java

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

It will show `Start` because the `Karte` already pop out from `stack`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Every time I change Activity I close the previous one, except the Main. OK, this was helpfull thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

On your "Einstellungen" activity, override the onBackPressed method to handle navigation:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Start.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

When you navigate from "Karte" to "Einstellungen" and from "Start" to "Karte" you should finish() your activity too to avoid navigation issues.